# #1052 - Column 'bookings.chauffeur_req' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE VIEW chauffeursreuqired AS 
SELECT  customers.customer_id, customers.fname, customers.lname, bookings.chauffeur_req, bookings.booking_id
FROM bookings, customers inner join bookings
ON customers.customer_id = bookings.customer_id;
```

Hey all, so Im trying to create a view using an inner join. im getting the error code as in the title. Anyone has an idea what it means that it is 'ambiguous'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
FROM bookings, customers inner join bookings
```

You are joining `bookings` to `customers` (using the implicit join operator `,`) and then to `bookings` again. So you have two `bookings` table in your `JOIN` and MySQL can't determine which one to fetch that column from.

You probably only meant to include `bookings` once, try changing your query to

```
FROM customers inner join bookings
```

Or if you *do* need to join the bookings table twice, you can add an alias to the table names to allow them to be distinguished from each other i.e.

```
FROM bookings AS bookings_1, customers inner join bookings AS bookings_2
```